# Typescript inherit return from array values

Tags: typescript

Let's say I got a file that stores variables, with an array with constant values like this:

```js
// file: variables.ts

/**
 * An array that stores the image types
 *
 * **The order is important! Sorted from less important to most important**
 */
export const IMAGE_TYPES: Readonly<string[]> = ['small', 'medium', 'large'];
```

Now when I hover over this in my IDE I get a simple return type like this:
`const IMAGE_TYPES: readonly string[]`

If I wanted to add return types in the same order I can do it like this:

```js
// file: variables.ts

/**
 * An array that stores the image types
 *
 * **The order is important! Sorted from less important to most important**
 */
export const IMAGE_TYPES: Readonly<['small', 'medium', 'large']> = ['small', 'medium', 'large'];
```

The hover is now: `const IMAGE_TYPES: readonly ['small', 'medium', 'large']` which is what I want

However, this violates DRY pinciples and causes double typings, is there a way I can infer the values or the types from one another? The value of the array will never change and the order should always stay the same as shown in the JSDoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the same type (`readonly ['small', 'medium', 'large']`) like this:

```
export const IMAGE_TYPES = ['small', 'medium', 'large'] as const;
```

For more info, see [const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions)